# Why is StreamReader hitting EndOfStream before BaseStream does?

Tags: c#, io, streamreader

Disclaimer: I'm bad at I/O

I've got a gigantic compressed text file that I'm trying to iterate through, line-by-line.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
using (var bz2 = new BZip2InputStream(stream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(bz2))
{
   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
      string line = reader.ReadLine();
      // etc
```

However, I'm reaching EndOfStream at line 40 and I have no idea why. Help!

Answer (score -2):

I would replace StreamReader by an BinaryReader. You may find the same code [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader)

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            R();
        }

        static void R()
        {
            // 1.
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(
                File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // 2.
                // Position and length variables.
                int pos = 0;
                // 2A.
                // Use BaseStream.
                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    // 3.
                    // Read integer.
                    int v = b.ReadInt32();
                    Console.WriteLine(v);

                    // 4.
                    // Advance our position variable.
                    pos += sizeof(int);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why not:

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
using (var bz2 = new BZip2InputStream(b))
```

Comment: How would that help with text data?

Comment: The end of a Stream is reached when a Stream.Read returns zero. A zipped file may contain one or many zeros, so Stream.Read will not read the entire file (perhaps not a byte), while BinaryReader will read the entire file based upon the file length.

Comment: using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))

            using (var bz2 = new BZip2InputStream(stream))

            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(bz2))
            {

Tried it; same issue as before.

Comment: *The end of a Stream is reached when a Stream.Read returns zero* - I think there's some confusion here. The Read(..) on a Stream(or StreamReader) that potentially returns zero indicating EOF places the data it gets from the underlying source into an array and returns an integer that the caller uses to know what range of chars/bytes in the array are validly recently read. It does not trip over the data that it transfers into the array, stop at the first 0x00 and return 0. The StreamReader.Read that reads a single char returns -1 if the end of the stream has been reached